# Deploying AppMaker app on multiple domains

Tags: google-app-maker

This is more of a general question about the future of AppMaker I guess... I have a few ideas that I would like to try out - mostly some tools that could help my clients - and I was wondering if there will be a way to deploy an app made with AppMaker to multiple domaine.

A (dumb) example would be to create a Task management app that you can centrally develop and deploy as a Saas service to multiple clients.

I would be interested to hear some insights before investing too much time in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, App Maker applications are restricted to the domain of their owner. However, you can export an App Maker application and import it in multiple domains and possibly share the same Google Cloud SQL backend. Keep in mind that sharing the same database will be challenging when it comes to changing the schema since you will have to synchronize updating the applications in the different domains.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is helpful.