# Including external developers in Google App Maker

Tags: google-app-maker

Is developing with App Maker restricted to accounts in the G Suite tenant where the App Maker apps were created?

Or have I missed a way to include external developers in the engineering process (eg. gmail accounts or other G Suite Orgs)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, only users in your G Suite domain can create and edit App Maker apps in your domain.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that only accounts in the domain can edit apps in the client domain, but developers **can** create apps or templates in a developer domain, export the app, then an admin can import the app into the client domain.  It can then be maintained there, but only by client domain users.

Comment: Firstly with the developer also gaining access to the EAP with a G Suite Business tenant at this stage. Then with these caveats described here:  [Deploying AppMaker app on multiple domains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41467659/deploying-appmaker-app-on-multiple-domains/41470683#41470683)